# Positioning Simple Modal PopUp near to the trigger link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) plugin to create a pup Up in My web page

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="txt-panel" id="124853" >

    <div class="container">
      <p>some text,...<a href="#" class="poper"> read more</a></p>
      <p class="popup" style="display:none" id="P1">More text, this will be a popup</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt-panel" id="5464641" >

    <div class="container">
      <p>some text2,...<a href="#" class="poper"> read more</a></p>
      <p class="popup" style="display:none" id="P2">More text, this will be a popup2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
  $(".poper").click(function(e){
    $(this).parents('.container').find(".popup").modal({
      overlayClose:true,
      escClose:true,
      maxWidth:500,
      overlayClose: true,
      opacity:50,
      containerCss:{background:"#f5d495"}
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

This works good. But only problem is that PopUp comes at the center of the page. But I want popup to come right above my anchor tag (class="popup"). Is it possible with Simple Modal popup. Or is there any other better way to achieve what I am trying to achieve? Like any other plugin?

### Note: [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/zodajaro/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set position option

```
    $(function(){
      var anchorPosition = $(".popup").position();
      $(".poper").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.container').find(".popup").modal({
          overlayClose:true,
          escClose:true,
          maxWidth:500,
          overlayClose: true,
          opacity:50,
          position:[anchorPosition.top,anchorPosition.left],
          containerCss:{background:"#f5d495"}
       });

      });
    });
```

Comment: Any specific error in console or position is still center of page

Comment: Without fiddle it is difficult to debug, but can you check the values of anchorPosition.top and anchorPosition.left

Comment: I don't understand it .Can you explain a littler moer. How can I check the values?

Comment: Add console.log(anchorPosition.top +" "+ anchorPosition.left) in your code and see what values are you getting for anchor, check in browser console if using FF see in firebug console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55495/discussion-between-sandeeproop-and-athul).

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle couldn't work,but i think you can also use jQuery's`.appendTo();` and stick the modal to the desired relative container for better position control.This should happen right before the modal pops.

Comment: I don't completely get you. Can you add a code sample?